# Why are my 5 HTML buttons not displaying in one row when set to 20% max width?

Tags: html, css, button, display

My 5 HTML buttons are set to 20% max width and should all fit in 1 row, but it's displaying in 2 rows. Why?

I have 2 beginner questions.

I am new to Javascript/CSS/HTML, and have learned a few basics of coding in Python.

I made "index.html" for the main code, with a "style.css" file and "main.js" file made as empty placeholders for the future. I also made "page1.html", "page2.html", "page3.html", "page4.html", "page5.html" for the 5 main pages of the app that I am making. I make 5 buttons on the main "index.html" page, that take the user to the 5 different pages based on which button they click.

**QUESTION 1:**

Below is my code for "index.html" which is mostly working. But why are the 5 buttons not displaying all in a single row at the bottom of the screen? They should each have width set to 20% of the screen's max width, so all 5 should fit perfect. Instead, the 5th button gets bumped down to a 2nd row. If I change their widths to 19% of max width, they all fit, but it should work with them at 20% of max width, so why is it not all fitting when the 5 buttons are set at 20% of max width?

Code from "index.html" listed here:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<style>
.bottom-buttons {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
.bottom-buttons button {
  width: 20%;
  height: 5%;
}
</style>

</head>
<body>
    <div class="bottom-buttons">
        <a href="page1.html"><button>Button 1</button></a>
        <a href="page2.html"><button>Button 2</button></a>
        <a href="page3.html"><button>Button 3</button></a>
        <a href="page4.html"><button>Button 4</button></a>
        <a href="page5.html"><button>Button 5</button></a>
      </div>

</body>
</html>
```

**QUESTION 2:**

If I cut all of the lines of code in between  and , and paste it into "style.css" it causes the button layout to be undone. I thought you could choose to put CSS code in its own "style.css" file, or, in the main HTML file in between  and ?

Is this true if certain criteria are met? What would I have to change to make it work the same with the CSS code swapped into the CSS file instead? Trying to get a feel for the right and wrong way to do things down the road.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Question 1

### Default Behaviour Of Browsers

By default browser always add spaces between some elements, including buttons because of carriage returns, new lines or white spaces. Dont worry this happens when our code editor's formatter format the code to increase readabilty. In your case the newlines characters added between each `<a></a>` tag. Demonstration without formatting the code works well:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <title>Document</title>
        <style>
            .bottom-buttons {
                position: fixed;
                bottom: 0;
                width: 100%;
                /* font-size: 0px; */
            }

            .bottom-buttons button {
                /* font-size: 14px; */
                width: 20%;
                height: 5%;
            }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="bottom-buttons"><a href="page1.html"><button>Button 1</button></a><a href="page2.html"><button>Button 2</button></a><a href="page3.html"><button>Button 3</button></a><a href="page4.html"><button>Button 4</button></a><a href="page5.html"><button>Button 5</button></a>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

### What If I Want To Format The Code

Dont worry we have solution for it you just have to set the font size of the parent element to zero then specify the font size of the buttons and boom. Just like that:

```
.bottom-buttons {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 0px;
}

.bottom-buttons button {
    font-size: 14px;
    width: 20%;
    height: 5%;
}
```

Have a look after doing this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <title>Document</title>
  <style>
    .bottom-buttons {
      position: fixed;
      bottom: 0;
      width: 100%;
      font-size: 0px;
    }
    
    .bottom-buttons button {
      font-size: 14px;
      width: 20%;
      height: 5%;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="bottom-buttons">
    <a href="page1.html"><button>Button 1</button></a>
    <a href="page2.html"><button>Button 2</button></a>
    <a href="page3.html"><button>Button 3</button></a>
    <a href="page4.html"><button>Button 4</button></a>
    <a href="page5.html"><button>Button 5</button></a>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

### Not The Part Of Answer But Advice

You can see in above snippet there are no spaces between button but if you try to give same margin to the button. Again same issue you will face. Now i will suggest to use flexbox. It is a great tool to handle layouts. You can get more details about it [here](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox.asp). After using flexbox you can give margin of your choice to seprate the buttons and code will look like:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <title>Document</title>
  <style>
    .bottom-buttons {
      position: fixed;
      bottom: 0;
      width: 100%;
      display: flex;
    }
    
    .bottom-buttons a {
      width: 20%;
      margin: 0 10px;
    }
    
    .bottom-buttons button {
      width: 100%;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="bottom-buttons">
    <a href="page1.html"><button>Button 1</button></a>
    <a href="page2.html"><button>Button 2</button></a>
    <a href="page3.html"><button>Button 3</button></a>
    <a href="page4.html"><button>Button 4</button></a>
    <a href="page5.html"><button>Button 5</button></a>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

## Question 2

Yes, if you have to use the code for multiple html files, it is a good approach to do it in a separate file. Here is a good detail how it can be done.

1. Put the styles in separate file i.e in styles.css
2. Link the styles with html with following line `<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">`

[More details about linking styles](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_howto.asp)

Comment: Thank you. Everything you included was able to fix both of my questions. I appreciate the extra info, advice, and links! I'll have to give more attention and thought to things like borders and padding.

Comment: @WestPole Upvote the answer it will be helpful for others to choose he best option among the given

Comment: I did. StackOverflow alerted me that my upvotes are logged, but not visible, due to my account still being new.

Comment: yeah you need 15 reputation atleast to upvote an answer....

Answer (score 1):

Adding this to the "index.html"  section allowed my CSS code to be swapped to the "style.css" file:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
```

And the button spacing issue was resolved by changing my button code in "style.css" to this:

```
.bottom-buttons {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 0px;
}

.bottom-buttons button {
    font-size: 14px;
    width: 20%;
    height: 5%;
}
```

Thanks to all who helped!

Comment: be aware to post your own solutions that had been already answered by someone.. there is no need to post what you had got helpful instead you can upvote and accept by clicking on tick the answer to tell others that this is helpful question for me....

Answer (score 0):

The reason that your buttons are wrapping to the second line is because when you are setting width, the width property does not include padding, margins or borders. One easy fix is the set the width of the buttons to 1fr (1 fraction of the space remaining):

```
.bottom-buttons button {
  width: 1fr;
  height: 5%;
}
```

This will take into account the properties I mentioned above, while allowing you to dynamically add and remove buttons without breaking the layout. Another way you could do this is by using grid layouts and flexboxes, the latter being my preferred method to do this.

As for your second question, I have limited information but in order for styles on a second css document to take affect, you have to link them in the head. You can do this by putting this code into the head of your main html document.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">
```

If you do not do this, then the HTML code doesn't even know that your custom css styles even exist, and as a result doesn't affect the changes.

Comment: The 1fr code didn't quite work, but opened my eyes to new code options to explore. Thanks!

Comment: can you send me a google drive link to your source code? @WestPole

Answer (score 0):

input element's like `<button>` by default have their own browser styles that overlap with the styles you're setting (`buttons` usually have `border` and `padding` by default)

check out https://css-tricks.com/overriding-default-button-styles/

you might try setting the width on the `<a>` element instead

```
.bottom-buttons a {
  width: 20%;
  height: 5%;
}
```

for Q2, you can definitely break out the styles into their own file

add the contents within your `<style>` tags into a `styles.css` file and reference that file in your html with `<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">`

Comment: I will check out the CSS tricks links, thanks! The stylesheet change makes total sense and for some reason I thought it was always included in the auto doctype code. I'll make sure I always manually add that part. Thanks!